# Convert matrix containg edges and vertices into igraph data.frame and obtaining eigenvector centrality

Tags: r, social-networking

I have directed trade data from industries(18) located in origin countries (29), which export to destination countries(29). Using this data set  I want to calculate the eigenvector centrality of each exporting industry in each origin country.

At first I reshaped the orginal data frame to long to wide

```
dcast(tiva.eigen, Country+Industry~Partner, value.var="va.export")
```

from the orginal data

```
|Country       |Industry |Partner        |va.export|
|:-------------|:--------|:--------------|:--------|
|United.States |20T22    |Slovenia       |24.1     |
|United.States |20T22    |South.Africa   |153.2    |
|United.States |20T22    |Spain          |491      |
|United.States |20T22    |Turkey         |232.9    |
|United.States |20T22    |United.Kingdom |2101.1   |
|United.States |20T22    |United.States  |0        |
```

I thus obtained following data frame.

```
|    |Country       |Industry |Australia |Austria |Belgium |
|:---|:-------------|:--------|:---------|:-------|:-------|
|517 |United.States |45       |66.3      |16.5    |40.5    |
|518 |United.States |50T55    |1348.5    |452.5   |1057.8  |
|519 |United.States |60T64    |2117.6    |374.3   |1275    |
|520 |United.States |65T67    |905.8     |489.5   |673.7   |
|521 |United.States |70T74    |3289.6    |1027.8  |2808.4  |
|522 |United.States |75T95    |392.8     |75.3    |202.9   |
```

Next I created for each industry a seperate matrix, which represents the  exports from the  exporter countries(i) to the importer country (j)

```
  tive.01t05<-  subset(tive.eigen,Industry=="01T05",select=c
  ("Country","Partner","va.export"))
```

After normalizing the columns I end up with this matrix, which includes information about the Exporter Country(i) as matrix rowname and the importer country (j) as column name and the cells are column normalized exports (x_i,j).

```
   |               | Australia|   Austria|   Belgium|    Canada|     Czech.Republic|
   |:--------------|---------:|---------:|---------:|---------:|--------------:|
   |Australia      | 0.0000000| 0.0027764| 0.0054247| 0.0295493|      0.0412588|
   |Austria        | 0.0172326| 0.0000000| 0.0040170| 0.0023143|      0.0408378|
   |Belgium        | 0.0074759| 0.0076592| 0.0000000| 0.0031181|      0.0107357|
   |Canada         | 0.0168525| 0.0013882| 0.0101627| 0.0000000|      0.0017893|
   |Czech.Republic | 0.0059554| 0.0898516| 0.0036394| 0.0016322|      0.0000000|
```

I loaded this weighting matrix with the edge names in R with the command graph adjacency and extracted the edges, the weights and the vertices

```
  test<-graph.adjacency(tive.01t05,weighted=TRUE)
  test2<-get.data.frame(test, what=c("edges"))
  vertice.test.01t05<-get.data.frame(test, what=c("vertices"))
  test2[,3]<- NULL
  g.test.01t05<-graph.data.frame(test2, directed=T,vertice.test.01t05)
```

However computing the eigenvecor with

```
evcent(g.test.01t05,directed=T)
```

I obtain an error message

```
   In .Call("R_igraph_eigenvector_centrality", graph, directed, scale,     :
    At centrality.c:362 :Weighted directed graph in eigenvector    centrality
```

Comment: Why do you need the eigenvector centrality in particular? In all cases, you need first to construct the network of the trade among countries. From the data you have, it looks like you need to model your network as a multiplex network.

Comment: I need the eigenvector centrality to compare them to an theoretical export measure, which I obtained before for each Industry in each orgin country. As I still have to normalize the column, I actually created a dataframe for each industry.  In a later step I will normalize each eigenvector centrality for each Industry in each country to a Benchmark country and industry.